# BaseRequestOptions vs Interceptors in Angular 4

Tags: angular, request, http-headers, local-storage

BaseRequsetOtions does not work with async operations, e.g.: reading token from LocalStorage (request is sent before token is added to headers).
I understand that Interceptor can accomplish this, e.g.: read token from storage, which returns a promise, and then on resolve add to headers and call next.handle(req).

What is the purpose then of having both these classes? It seems that Interceptors are more robust.

Comment: I think you are mixing two different APIs: the new http client api and the old http api.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out after some more reading.